# How to search and store data from a website?

Tags: python, html, parsing

I have a list of products that I would like to search in the following website [bb farma](http://www.bbfarma.com/atc-code/search-result.html)
. Ideally when inserting a product the search comes out with a list of medicines in a table as in the picture below:[image: the following is an example of a search of the product: "Actimmune"]
Now, the aim is to make a search in Python (with BeautifulSoup I guess) for each product I have stored in a list and save the number called ATC in the table if the search is successful (e.g. with a try and an except).
The html when inspecting the page is the following:
[image: Inspector]

Alternatively, maybe I could parse the table [tab](http://www.bbfarma.com/atc-code/search-result.html) directly.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please Kindly post the code so any one can guide you,It will help to guide you

Comment: Thank you all for the replies! Very usefull indeed. @stackz your solution did work well!

Answer (score 0):

```
url = 'Whatever URL'

def get_list():
    s = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
    med_tags = s.findAll('td', 'class=small')

    med_list = []
    for med in med_tags:
        try:
            whatever = med.find('a').get('href')
            med_list.append({
                'whatever med': whatever
            })
        except:
            print('Something did not work')
```

Comment: My code is only a guide; not meant to totally work, you would have to debug the rest